# Multidimensional Array (1 to #) - Lbound is showing as 0, not 1?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array that holds values like this:  `theArray(1,0) = "Batman"`and`theArray(1,1) = "Gotham"`

I have my setup like this (just to get the super heros in their `0` spot first):

```
Sub deleteme()
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstArray() As Variant
ReDim firstArray(1 To 5)

firstArray = Array("Batman", "Superman", "Joker", "Rorschach", "Dr. Manhattan")

Dim theArray() As Variant
ReDim theArray(1 To 5, 1)
For i = LBound(firstArray) To UBound(firstArray)
    theArray(i, 1) = firstArray(i) ''' ERROR THROWN HERE
    Debug.Print theArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

However, when that gets to the `theArray(i,1)...` I get the error

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

I can see why - it's because `LBound(firstArray)` is equal to `0`. Therefore, I'm trying to set `theArray(0,1)` to a value, but `theArray(0,#)` doesn't exist! I understand this.

How come though `LBound` is equal to 0, when I'd think it'd be 1?  Is `LBound()` always going to be `0` with arrays?

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks for any help/ideas.

Comment: `ReDim firstArray(1 To 5)` **serves no purpose**.  `firstArray = Array(...)` discards any existing contents and/or declaration and ReDims `firstArray` according to the number of elements within `Array(...)`.  The lower bound of firstArray will be zero or the value specified by the `Option Base` statement.  I do not think any of the current answers makes this clear.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - ah, thanks for the clarification on the `ReDim`. I suppose that's mainly used when building dynamic arrays.

Comment: `ReDim` can only be used for Dynamic (`Dim myArray() As String`) arrays.  If you try it on a static (`Dim myArray(N To M) As String`) array, your code will not execute.  My point is that `myArray = Array(...)` includes an implicit `ReDim` so you cannot set `myArray`'s dimensions in advance. I think the answers, which are broadly correct, should have told you to discard the `ReDim` rather than change it.

Comment: Ah! "If you try it on a static array, your code will not execute".  That's why I had the `ReDim` lines, because at first I was trying set the array with `N to M` in it.  Thanks so much for this, its great clarification :D

Comment: You are welcome.  There is always something new to learn.  Experimenting for this question I learnt the lower bound set for `myArray = Array(...)` is controlled by `Option Base`.  I have been told more than once by experts that the lower bound is **always** zero and that my habitual use of `LBound(myArray)` is unnecessary.  I now know I was correct to be unsure.  The lower bound was zero whenever I tested it but I could not find any documentation that said it would always be zero.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - yeah, I use `LBound()` all the time, regardless if I'm using `myArray(1 to 100)` or not.  I really started looking in to the whole `myArray(1 to 100)` because when looping with cells, I got annoyed with having to always add one to `i` for  something like (for row 1) `For i = 0 to 100: .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = myArray(i)`...but now I understand a lot more! Kudos to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, arrays are 0-based, but you're explicitly setting your theArray to be 1 based. There are two options the first is to ReDim theArray(0 to 4,1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteme()
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstArray() As Variant
ReDim firstArray(0 To 4)

firstArray = Array("Batman", "Superman", "Joker", "Rorschach", "Dr. Manhattan")

Dim theArray() As Variant
ReDim theArray(0 To 4, 1)
For i = LBound(firstArray) To UBound(firstArray)
    theArray(i, 1) = firstArray(i) ''' ERROR THROWN HERE
    Debug.Print theArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

the other is to set the Option Base 1 at the top, like so:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub deleteme()
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstArray() As Variant
ReDim firstArray(1 To 5)

firstArray = Array("Batman", "Superman", "Joker", "Rorschach", "Dr. Manhattan")

Dim theArray() As Variant
ReDim theArray(1 To 5, 1)
For i = LBound(firstArray) To UBound(firstArray)
    theArray(i, 1) = firstArray(i) ''' ERROR THROWN HERE
    Debug.Print theArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Pick one or the other, don't do both.

Comment: Thanks - your last statement answered my question on the one above I believe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `Option Base 1` to the beginning of your script:

```
Option Base 1

Sub deleteme()
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstArray() As Variant
ReDim firstArray(1 To 5)

firstArray = Array("Batman", "Superman", "Joker", "Rorschach", "Dr. Manhattan")

Dim theArray() As Variant

ReDim theArray(1 To 5, 1)
For i = LBound(firstArray) To UBound(firstArray)
    theArray(i, 1) = firstArray(i) ''' ERROR THROWN HERE
    Debug.Print theArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it.  That makes sense - thanks!  So, with that knowledge, if I use `Option Base 1` at the top, then I should plan on making *all* arrays starting at 1?  Or could I do some like `myArray(1 to 5)` and another `mySecondArray(2)`?  Or is that "bad form" and I shouldn't mix the bases - pick a base and stick to it? (Does that question make sense)?

Comment: The `(1 to 5)` syntax is one of the many reasons why some people really hate Visual Basic. There are too many gotchas for a supposedly 'simple' language. I recommend that you pick a style and stick to it through out your code. If you set `Option Base 1`, `mySecondArray` will have index 1 and 2. If not, it will have index 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you set 
`firstArray=Array("Batman","Superman","Joker","Rorschach","Dr.Manhattan")`, it created an Array (right hand side) and set firstArray to it. By default, arrays are 0 based when created (unless you use options such as Option Base 1 referenced by the other comments on this thread). Lbound(firstArray) before setting equal to Array is equal to 1. If you individually set each firstArray element (`firstArray(1)="Batman",firstArray(2)="Superman"`, etc) then lbound(firstArray) would be 1.